# Using GP Web Service: How do I delete a SalesOrderLine from a SalesOrder?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

Can someone help me delete a SalesOrderLine from a SalesOrder?

I'm using the GP WS Native Endpoint

My code executes without an error.

However, after updating the SalesOrder, the line I removed still remains.

```
var salesDocumentKeyObject = new SalesDocumentKey {Id = salesDocumentKey, CompanyKey = this.CompanyKey};

var salesOrder = this.DynamicsGpClient.GetSalesOrderByKey(salesDocumentKeyObject, this.Context);

var newLines = salesOrder.Lines.Where(l => l.Key.LineSequenceNumber != lineItemSequence).ToArray();

salesOrder.Lines = newLines;

var salesOrderUpdatePolicy =      this.DynamicsGpClient.GetPolicyByOperation("UpdateSalesOrder", this.Context);

this.DynamicsGpClient.UpdateSalesOrder(salesOrder, this.Context, salesOrderUpdatePolicy);
```

Thank you for any help,

Karl

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft Dynamics GP Web Service has poor documentation and examples.**

Do delete a sales order line, you retrieve the order, locate the line to delete and set the sales order line property, DeleteOnUpdate to true, and then save the order.

Updated code below:

```
var salesDocumentKeyObject = new SalesDocumentKey {Id = salesDocumentKey, CompanyKey = this.CompanyKey};
var salesOrder =    this.DynamicsGpClient.GetSalesOrderByKey(salesDocumentKeyObject, this.Context);

var target= salesOrder.Lines.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Key.LineSequenceNumber == lineItemSequence);
if (target != null) {
target.DeleteOnUpdate = true;
}

var salesOrderUpdatePolicy = this.DynamicsGpClient.GetPolicyByOperation("UpdateSalesOrder", this.Context);

this.DynamicsGpClient.UpdateSalesOrder(salesOrder, this.Context, salesOrderUpdatePolicy);
```